# Prestashop Table in module helper form

Tags: php, oop, module, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

In module helper form there is those instructions in blocktopmenu.php

```
$helper->table = $this->table;
$helper->identifier = $this->identifier;
```

$this->table is inherited from Module class

```
protected $table = 'module';
```

Which table the module belongs to? also for the identifier attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just as it says.

The table is `module` without prefix and identifier attribute means primary key which is `id_module`.

Comment: Db::getInstance()->insert($this->table, array('name' => $this->name, 'active' => 1, 'version' => $this->version)); in Module.php so name will be the module name